Questions about the proof of the Efron-Stein inequality
Let $Z$ be a bounded random variable, $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be independant random variable and $\Delta_i  = E_{i}[Z] - E_{i-1}[Z]$ where $E_i$ denote the conditionnal expectation with respect to $X_1, \dots, X_i$.
To prove the Efron-Stein inequality, we prove that if $j<  i$, $E[\Delta_i\Delta_j]= 0$. I'm wondering if we can generalize this kind of equality. For example, is $E[\Delta_i \Delta_j \Delta_k^2]= 0$ also true whenever $i,j$ & $ k$ are pairwise distinct?
